# C# async method called twice

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building an android app using c# and Xamarin.
I have an method that creates a countdown timer, and to not block the UI the method is async. 
After the countdown is finished, the method call another method, that send something to the server.  If the server respond is "true", the second method call a third method, which also is an async method.
The problem is that the third method is being called twice, and then I see there is 2 task running in the background.

**First method (countdown timer):**

```
public async Task RunTimerToScheduledTime(DateTime dt)
    {         
        while (savedInstanceState == SavedInstanceState.OnScheduled && dt > DateTime.Now)
        {
            var sub = dt - DateTime.Now;
            RunOnUiThread(() => ScheduledCuontdownTv.Text = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", sub));
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            if(Convert.ToInt32(sub.TotalSeconds) == 60)
            {
                Log.Debug("WNS", "RunTimerToScheduledTime - 60 sec left");
            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(sub.TotalSeconds) == 5)
            {
                Log.Debug("WNS", "RunTimerToScheduledTime - 5 sec left");
            }
        }
        await ScheduledRideIsDone();
}
```

**Second method (the method that send something to server):**

```
 public async Task ScheduledRideIsDone()
    {
        MakeLoadingLayout();
        try
        {
            var res = await Api.UpdateScheduledRideStatus(SoluVars.Me.IdString, SceheduledRideStatus.Done);
            if (!res)
            {
                GlobalMethods.ShortAlertDialog(this, "bla", "bla");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                await MakeActive();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Debug("WNS", ex.Message);
            GlobalMethods.ShortAlertDialog(this, "bla", "bla");
        }
    }
```

**Third method (the one that being called twice):**

```
  public async Task MakeActive()
    {
        loadingActive.Show();
        try
        {

            var res = await Api.Transofrm(id, currentLocationCoords);
            if (res)
            {

                /// Some long tasks


                //Task that should run in the background from now on
                await Task.WhenAll(AskForCurrentCityLocation(), UpdateActiveDriverTimeStamp(), UpdateWaitingCustomerAdapter());  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Debug("WNS", ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }
```

What is the problem here? Thank you!

Comment: And who calls these methods?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even call the `MakeMeAnActiveDriver()` method once. Please read [mcve], so you understand what kind of code is required as part of a useful, well-written Stack Overflow question. See also [ask], including all the articles linked at the bottom of that page, for more advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I edit the code, sorry. The code is longer and I deleted some unimportant lines and changed the named to make it cleaner. @John Ephraim Tugado as I explained in the question the first method call the second method, and second method call the third method. The problem is that the third method run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint into the method, and then look into call stack who called it the second time.